# How can I upgrade the Mech Bay?

Tags: battletech

There are clear indicators in the mech bay that it can be upgraded in order to store more mechs. Unfortunately I couldn’t find any information on how to perform these upgrades.

Is there an interface to upgrade your ship or ist that something that comes with the story progression?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To be able to upgrade your ship, including the Mech Bay, you first need to progress a little in the story line.

So it makes sense do to the first few story line missions rather early in the game.